# WinRT XAML TextBox bad performance

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Slow feedback when there is a long text inside a TextBox with FontFamily="Segoe Script" especially when there is very long word without spaces (just copy and paste a word without spaces).

Check out the example:
https://github.com/inTagger/Bugs/tree/master/TextBoxPerformanceProblemWinRT

Is there any workaround to increase the performance?

Comment: Verified. Awful performance. No idea.

Comment: Can you verify that `RichEditBox` has the same behavior?